# Magento 2 - How to add a background image for each category from a category attribute

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2

I am working with Magento2 2.2.7 CE

I am Looking into the possibility of trying to set a page background image for each category. I am aware that I can setup category attributes through the setup script to hold image file path details.

I need some direction on which class / function I need to preference / plugin into to change the page background per category depending on the value that will be held in custom attribute for category background image.

This a research question at the moment but I am looking to code and keep the functionality changes in a module.